# Populate datagridview with FileVersionInfo

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would need to fill a datagrid with the values of versioninfo prellevato by a double foreach.

> incorro error: `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo (file)`; (incorrect syntax)

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\TEMP\");

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.GetDirectories())
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
    {
        FileVersionInfo verInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file);
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Version";
        string[] row = new string[] { verInfo.ProductVersion };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You do know version numbers are not necessarily doubles, You get versions like 3.14.2

Comment: what exactly are you having problems with? what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BugFinder already pointed you to the documentation of the method [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

It takes only a `string` as parameter. So you should give it the filename and not the `FileInfo`

```
FileVersionInfo verInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file.FullName);
```